# Local scope and DataArrays.DataArray

Tags: julia

I am having a strange issue with Julia, working with DataArrays.DataArray.

I will try to describe my problem using an example (simplified) from the official documentation:

```
x = 1
function bar()
    x = 10 # local
    println(x) # 10
    return 1
end

bar();
println(x) # 1
```

This function changes the local value of x, but doesn't modifies its global value.

Now, let's say I have the following:

```
using DataFrames;
x = @data([1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]);
function bar()
    x[1,1] = 1000000 # local
    println(x[1, 1]) # 1000000
    return 1
end

bar();
println(x[1, 1]) # it should be 1, but it is 1000000
```

Could you please clarify why this is the case and how can I let Julia behave normally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second example you are indexing into a variable and thus it will search for it in the global scope and mutate it if it is there. i.e for x[1,1] to equal something then x must already exist.

In the first example you have created a new variable in the local scope as expected.

Does that make sense? FYI this is unrelated to the DataFrames type and the same would apply to a normal array.

Comment: Alright, I've got it. I am still in doubt since I am having the same issue even if I let bar to accept x as an argument. In that case, the function bar should have a local version of x, isn't it? Why is it still accessing to the global x?

Comment: nope, functions can mutate their arguments. if you want to explicitly create a local version then add local before i.e. `local x = "whatever"`

Comment: @AlexanderMorley `local x = "whatever"` does not make a copy, which is what it sounds like @merch wants to do.

Comment: sure, I wasn't sure whether @merch wanted to make a copy or just wanted to make sure the global variable wasn't mutated by using `x` as a variable name. Maybe I should have said "if you want to explicity assign x to a variable in the local scope". Is there a way of making a local copy with the same name?